# Find how many times a string appears in another? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string

How do I find how many times a string appears in another?

Example, if I input two strings:
message miSHdeOJfsfsOJdosIhisdaIhfidfgOJsde

So, it appears once, therefore the output should be YES.

It must be case sensitive as well, example:
CaseSensitive casesensitive should output "NO" because it doesn't appear.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string a[100],b[100];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(a[j].find(b[j]))
        cout << "YES" << endl;
        else
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried, what does it do, what does it not do...... (blah, blah, blah)

Comment: Use std::string::find inside a while loop with a counter to keep track

Comment: Updated what I got so far. I'm pretty much stuck... any help?

Comment: much better, note to the solvers, his 'to find' string is embedded, one character at a time in his 'lookup' string

Comment: If the number is >100, the program will overflow I guess. Anyway, the challenge I'm doing says 1<=N<=100 so I guess it's fine with their debugger.

Comment: Google for LCS (Longest common subsequence) and you will find a good algorithm for exactly this particular well-known problem that uses *dynamic programming*.

Answer (score 3):

`string::find` returns `string::npos` if nothing is found (not `0`) and the starting position if it is found, so your condition `if(a[j].find(b[j]))` is wrong.

Read [a reference manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find out how to use `find` properly.

(`find` will only find the search string if it occurs in one piece, i.e. it finds 'esag' in 'message' but not 'beer' in 'abaeaear' ! The latter requires more thought, if that is the task then you're probably meant to come up with your own algorithm.)

Comment: This is not homework, I'm doing challenges on spoj.com.

Comment: Here is my code:
`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string a[100],b[100];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string::size_type m;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i] >> b[i];
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        m=a.find(b[j]);
        cout << m << "YES" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}`
I'm getting error for line "m=a.find(b[j]);" saying "request for member 'find' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'std::string[100]"

Answer (score 0):

you might try something like this:

```
int find_n_substr( const string& s, const string& key){

    int n = 0;
    string::size_type sz = 0;

    while ( (sz = s.find (key,sz) ) != string::npos  ){
        sz++; /*otherwise you start searching at your previous match*/
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this only works if the EXACT word is there... I need to find between other words too, example to find key between kaeaya.